IQ test treningmozga with pluses and circles in grids
Please solve this puzzle for me

Source
https://m.treningmozga.com/

I have provided an answer to your question if you still any queries lmk

@tuấnlê Don't forget that you can accept answers to mark them as correct by clicking the checkmark icon next to them. It's not required, but it helps signal to other users that your puzzle has been solved.

Uh, I think the answer is in the image…

@TheEmptyStringPhotographer but the reasoning is not

The answer is

 Option 5

The pattern is…

 If you look column-wise, top to bottom, we are to combine the first tile with the second tile to produce the final tile. The outermost columns of the final tile each are the result of the ‘sum’ (ignoring positioning) of the outermost columns of the first two tiles and the middle row which is enclosed in a box is the result of a combination and then deduction of any common shapes…

For example

 If you look at the left hand column of tiles, on the left columns of those tiles we have 1 ball + 1 ball resulting 2 red balls. In the middle boxes: 2 plus signs - 1 plus sign resulting in 1 plus sign. On the right columns: red ball, plus sign and a plus resulting in a red ball and two plus signs.


 Applying the same idea to the rightmost column would result in option 5 exclusively.

